# jQueryMobile shows wrong height() value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, height

I have a really simply mark-up for a home/index screen/page for a jQM app:

```
<div id="home" class="container" data-role="page">
    <div class="grid-quarter">
        <a class="ui-link">
            <span class="grid-icon-container">
                <span class="grid-icon icon-lock"></span>
                <span class="grid-icon-text">LABEL TEXT</span>
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <!-- 3 x the same -->
</div>
```

#### Problem

Now that works fine on jsFiddle, but as soon as I throw the exact same code in my jQM app, the js `.height()` function (and every other try to get the height of an element) fails.

I wrote a function that checks every bit on any chance to determine the height and fails with jQM. It fails even if I'm trying to get it directly from the DOM object. And even when I see the DOM-object having the exact height set. Fun as it is: The `.width()` gets output correct.

I don't know where to start debugging this issue. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

---

#### Testing code

```
// Trigger on Load and Resize 
$( '#home' ).on( 
     'pageinit'
    ,function( event )
    {
        fitIconFont( '.icon-font' );
    }
);
// Fit on Window size change
$( window ).resize( function()
{
    fitIconFont( '.icon-font' );
} );

function fitIconFont( class_name )
{
    // DEBUG
    jQuery( class_name ).each( function( index, element ) 
    {
            // WORKS:
        $( this ).on( 'click', function () 
        {
            console.log( $( this ).height() );
        } );
        console.log( $( element ).css('width') );
        console.log( $( element ).width() );

            // FAILS with 20px as output
        console.log( $( element ).css('height') );
        console.log( $( element ).height() );
        console.log( element.scrollHeight );
        console.log( element.offsetHeight );
        console.log( element.clientHeight );
        console.log( element );

        console.log( $( this ).height() );
        console.log( $( this ).css('height') );
        console.log( this.scrollHeight );
        console.log( this.offsetHeight );
        console.log( this.clientHeight );
        console.log( this );
    } );
}
```

#### Screenshot from Chrome dev bar

[image]

[Link to jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/kaiser/qAcSR/1/)

Comment: Perhaps its a CSS issue, can you post any custom CSS? When you create your fiddle, are you including the CSS?

Comment: @JonathanRowny Yes, I didn't include the CSS as it's the _exact_ same on jsFiddle as in local dev env.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, the whole thing only works with adding both `on( 'pageinit' )` *AND* `( document ).ready()`.

Don't know why, but this way triggers right on desktop as well as mobile devices. Fun as it is: If I'm only using one of both: Nada, nothing, nix works.

Comment: wouldn't the correct replacement for `$(document).ready()` be `$(document).on('pageshow')` ?!

Comment: @tronc Try it in a fiddle

Comment: @tronc Long time since I worked on that. Realized [that I already had it there](http://jsfiddle.net/kaiser/qAcSR/) on `pageshow`. Still, if you want to add it separate answer...

Answer (score 1):

When you ran this code in JSFiddle you probably didn't mess with the settings on the left for when to load the JavaScript (located just above the Framework selection drop-down). By default it's set to `onLoad` which is the equivilent of `$(window).on('load', ...)`. When `window.load` fires all the assets will be loaded and styled properly so you can get an accurate height.

It's working in the `click` event handler because all the assets on the page have loaded and you can get an accurate reading. The `width` is probably being reported properly because it doesn't change once the page has fully loaded, which is what normally happens since block level elements take up 100% width by default.

I try to use the `no wrap (body)` setting in JSFiddle so the code runs at the same time as where I normally put the code (bottom of the document).

Comment: +1 For some reason it's even with `no wrap (body)` working in the fiddle. I'll set a link to the fiddle at the bottom of the Q, so you can take a look. Point is that I already corrected my mistake: move from `document ready` to `'pageinit'`. Still I get wrong output.

Answer (score 1):

### HTML

```
<div id="header">
    <h1>Header</h1>
</div>
<div id="home" data-role="page" class="container" style="background-color: #aaa;">
    <div class="grid-half " style="background-color: #009ee0;">
        <a href="#" class="ui-link">
            <span class="grid-icon-container">
                <span class="icon-font icon-a"></span>
                <span class="grid-icon-text">Label A</span>
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-half last" style="background-color: #FF00FF;">
        <a href="#" class="ui-link">
            <span class="grid-icon-container">
                <span class="icon-font icon-b"></span>
                <span class="grid-icon-text">Label B</span>
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-half btop" style="background-color: #FFFF00;">
        <a href="#" class="ui-link">
            <span class="grid-icon-container">
                <span class="icon-font icon-c"></span>
                <span class="grid-icon-text">Label C</span>
            </span>
        </a>
    </div> 
    <div class="grid-half last btop" style="background-color: #000;">
        <a href="#" class="ui-link">
            <span class="grid-icon-container">
                <span class="icon-font icon-d"></span>
                <span class="grid-icon-text">Label D</span>
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>       
</div>
```

### Script

```
function fitIconFont( elements ) 
{
    $( elements ).each( function( key, el )
        {
            var 
                container         = $( el ).parent()
                container_height = parseInt( $( container ).outerHeight( true ), 0 )
                new_icon_height  = parseInt( container_height * 0.75, 0 ) + 'px'
                new_label_height = parseInt( container_height * 0.25, 0 ) + 'px'
            ;

            // Set font-sizes for icon & label
            $( el ).css( 'font-size', new_icon_height );
            $( el ).next().css( 'font-size', new_label_height );

            // Debug print
            $( '#header' ).text( 'current heights: Container: ' + container_height + ' / ' );
            $( '#header' ).append( 'Icon: ' + new_icon_height + ' / ' );
            $( '#header' ).append( 'Label: ' + new_label_height );
        }
    );
}

// Trigger on Load and Resize 
// Fit on Window load
$( window ).on( 'load' )
{
    fitIconFont( '.icon-font' ) ;
}
// Fit on Window size change
$( window ).resize( function()
{
    fitIconFont( '.icon-font' );
} );

// Fit on Page Show
jQuery( '#home' ).on( 
     'pageshow'
    ,function( event )
     {
        fitIconFont( '.icon-font' );
     }
).trigger( 'updatelayout' );

// Fit on Orientation Change
jQuery( '#home' ).on( 
     'orientationchange'
    ,function( event )
     {
        fitIconFont( '.icon-font' );
     }
).trigger( 'updatelayout' );

/**
 * Update grid container height/width on change of device orientation
 */
$( '#home' ).on( 
    'orientationchange'
    ,function( e )
     {
         $( '.grid-half' ).each( function( index, el )
         {
             //if ( 'portrait' !== e.orientation )
             $( el ).width( window.innerWidth * .5 );
             $( el ).height( window.innerHeight * ( 'portrait' !== e.orientation ? .6 : .5 ) );
         } );
     }
);
```

### CSS

```
body, html { 
    height: 100%; 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
    font-size: 100%;
}
#header {
    height: 10%;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 1;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#header {
    text-align: center;
}
#home {
    width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
}
    /* Grid */
    .grid-half {
        display: table;
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        width: 49.8%;
        height: 50%;
    }
    .grid-half.last {
        border-left: 1px dashed white;
    }
    .grid-btop {
        border-top: 1px dashed white;
    }
        .grid-half .ui-link {
            display: table-cell;
            position: absolute;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            vertical-align: middle;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        .grid-half .grid-icon-container {
            display: block;
            position: relative;
            top: 25%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            height: 50%;
            width: 50%;
            border: 1px dotted #ddd;
        }
        .grid-half .icon-font {
            margin: 0 auto;
            position: relative;
            display: block;
            height: 75%;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #bdbddb;
        }
        .grid-icon-text {
            display: block;
            position: relative;
            height: 25%;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 1% auto 0;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: #fff;
        }

/* Icons */
[class^="icon-"]:before,
[class*=" icon-"]:before {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: normal;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: inherit;
    text-align: center;
}
.icon-a:before     { content: "C"; color: #FFFF00; }
.icon-b:before     { content: "M"; color: #009ee0; }
.icon-c:before     { content: "Y"; color: #000; }
.icon-d:before     { content: "K"; color: #FFFF00; }

/* Style */
#header,
a {
    color: #333;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/kaiser/qAcSR/